# Uploadify displays complete even if upload is unsuccessful

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I'm using uploadify straight out of the box, I havnt modified it in any way. It's uploading files great, so now I've got that sorted I wanted to sort out what happens if the file doesn't upload for any reason. I deleted the upload directory from the server so that the file can't be uploaded and tested what would happen. Unfortunately the uploader still says the file has been completed even though no upload directory exists, and the file hasnt been uploaded. I then modified the uploadify.php script so that the file doesn't get saved if it's the wrong file format. This worked great and prevented any files in the wrong format from being saved however the uploader still says the upload is complete. Does anyone know why this might be and what I can do to force an error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found sort of a solution here:

http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/6940/problems-triggering-onerror/#Item_4

at the bottom.

Basically it says if you want to return an error then do:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
exit;
```

It's a bit of a hack though because it might not be a 404 error you wish to return. It does the job though

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the documentation as if you need to use the "onError" option and possibly return "false" in the function you supply to it.

e.g.

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
  'uploader'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
  // Point to a non-existent back-end file so the error always triggers.
  'script'      : '/uploadify/uploadify-x.php',
  'cancelImg'   : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
  'folder'      : '/uploads',
  'onError'     : function (event,ID,fileObj,errorObj) {
      alert(errorObj.type + ' Error: ' + errorObj.info);
    }
});
```

See:

```
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onerror/
```

Regards
        Neil

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for your reply. I've tried returning false in the uploadify.php script if the file doesn't upload but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used UPLOADIFY, so I don't know how much help I can be. Does the "onError" event fire, e.g. if you put an "alert" message in the "onError function" (such as in the example above), do you get the alert or not?

Comment: The other thing the documentation says is that; The default function add the error class to the file queue item. So I suppose if it is detecting an error than you should check the "items" that have the class "error"